# iOSNotificationCenter.GetLastRespondedNotification() returns null when game starts from push notification

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

In Unity I am trying to get the notification data when the app is opened from a push notification on my iOS device. I am using the method `iOSNotificationCenter.GetLastRespondedNotification()` to ge thte last clicked notification, But it only works when the app is running in the background. If I kill the app and send a push notification and click on the notification the method returns null.

Note: I am using Playfab to get my notification.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Am I using the wrong method to get the notification data?